# Add XAML programmatically in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need to add programmatically some UI.

In order to do that I am creating each single Object and adding it to my main grid.

This way (I need to do that in a lambda function):

```
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
            StackPanel stkpanel = new StackPanel();
            stkpanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
             TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = "text1";
            Grid myGrid = new Grid();
            myGrid.Children.Add(textBlock);

            MainPage currentPage = (MainPage)(((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage);
            currentPage.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myGrid);
 ...
});
```

Is there a way to add to my MainPage.xaml another File.xaml and display the result?

I am using silverlight 8.1

Thanks

Comment: Load the file as a control and add it to the children of another grid?

Comment: please could provide an example or a link I am new to wp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There some different ways to do that.

### UserControl

One way is to create a user Control and use it direct in XAML or instantiate it in the code behind like a standard control. You can find a template in the *Add Item* dialog in Visual Studio.

### Pages

It is also possible to create a second page and Display them in a `Frame` tag. It is possible in XAML and code behind. Here is an example:

```
<Frame Margin="0,148,0,0" Name="myFrame"/>

myFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
```

### XamlReader

If you have a partial XAML code, stored in a file you can parse it manual and add the objects to the page. Your XAML must look like the following with the `xmlns` Attribut

```
<StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Button Content="BTN 1" />
    <Button Content="BTN 2" />
    <Button Content="BTN 3" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then you can parse it with `XamlReader`:

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///test.xaml");
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);

var panel = XamlReader.Load(await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file)) as StackPanel;
root.Children.Add(panel);
```

Be sure you set the *Build Action* of the XAML file to *Content*, if you will use it as an resource. You can also pass directly a string with XAML code to the `XamlReader.Load` function.